# jquery-easyui append node to treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jquery-easyui

i am using jquery-easyui Treeview.

i have the following code.

```
// append some nodes to the selected node
        var node = $('.JQTreeview').tree('find', 1234);

        $('.JQTreeview').tree('append', {
            parent: node.target,
             data:[{
                 id: 1235,
                 text:'new1'

         },{
                 text:'new2',
                 state:'closed',
                 children:[{
                         text:'subnew1'
                 },{
                         text:'subnew2'
                 }]
         }]
    });
```

The Code runs well but i can't see the newly added node.

Any help is greatly appriciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade easyui version to 1.3.4 would solve this issue.

http://www.jeasyui.com/download/v134.php